# Angular.js: use color code in $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch, lexer

how can I use a color code in a String variable and link this variable to a $watch expression?

```
$scope.$watch($scope.backgroundTextColor, function(){
      // code inside function
});
```

With the example code I get the next error:

```
"Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [#] in expression [#9c5c5c]...
```

Comment: And what is inside `// code inside function` ?

Comment: you have to show us a little more, can"t help you with that

Comment: $scope.$watch('backgroundTextColor', function(){
      // code inside function
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the Value of `$scope.backgroundTextColor`

You need to pass the name of the variable eg

```
$scope.$watch('backgroundTextColor', function(newValue, oldValue){
      // code inside function
});
```

Have a look at [Responding to Scope Changes](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/controllers/responding-to-scope-changes.html)

Comment: Nice answer! it worked! when I write the variable's name between quotes, and in the app I change the color, the debugger stop inside the watch function.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a magic string here.

The `$watch` function in Angular can either take in a function that returns the value that you want to watch, or a string that refers to the variable that you want to watch (a magic string).

The string will refer to the variable as if you are in the HTML. So if you are using the `$scope` (which it looks like you are) you need:

```
$scope.$watch('backgroundTextColor', function(newValue, oldValue){
      // code inside function
});
```

If you have an alias set (using `ControllerAs` for example) for the controller you will need to reference that:

```
$scope.$watch('ctrl.backgroundTextColor', function(newValue, oldValue){
      // code inside function
});
```

Otherwise you can use a function:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.backgroundTextColor;
}, function(newValue, oldValue){
      // code inside function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then placing the variable as is in the `$watch` expression, try to return the variable value:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return $scope.backgroundTextColor }, function() {
      // code inside function
});
```

I prefer using the variable itself and not its HTML string representation (`backgroundTextColor`), this way you are more agnostic to the view.